# Error al bajar proyecto en Spring desde el repositorio

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, maven

Hola Buenas tardes a todos, lo que sucede es que no puedo ejecutar un proyecto que baje desde un repositorio, pero me tira este error:

```
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTENCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:mbbn_mult_web_autodigitalweb_01' did not find a matching property.
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.78
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server built:          May 10 2017 15:02:19 UTC
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server number:         7.0.78.0
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: OS Name:               Windows 10
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: OS Version:            10.0
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Architecture:          amd64
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\CDMX\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\CDMX\Documents\Servidor\apache-tomcat-7.0.78
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\CDMX\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\CDMX\Documents\Servidor\apache-tomcat-7.0.78
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\CDMX\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\CDMX\Documents\Servidor\apache-tomcat-7.0.78\endorsed
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMACIÓN: La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\CDMX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\CDMX\Downloads\spring-tool-suite-3.8.4.RELEASE-e4.6.3-win32-x86_64\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.4.RELEASE;;.
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMACIÓN: Initialization processed in 755 ms
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio Catalina
jul 05, 2017 3:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.78
jul 05, 2017 3:41:22 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFORMACIÓN: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [125] milliseconds.
jul 05, 2017 3:41:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Error configurando escuchador de aplicación de clase com.bbva.jee.arq.spring.core.util.ArqSpringContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bbva.jee.arq.spring.core.util.ArqSpringContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:495)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5034)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

jul 05, 2017 3:41:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Error configurando escuchador de aplicación de clase com.bbva.jee.arq.spring.core.contexto.ArqSpringSessionListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bbva.jee.arq.spring.core.contexto.ArqSpringSessionListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:495)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5034)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

jul 05, 2017 3:41:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Error configurando escuchador de aplicación de clase org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:495)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5034)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

jul 05, 2017 3:41:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Se ha saltado la instalación de escuchadores de aplicación debido a error(es) previo(s)
jul 05, 2017 3:41:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
jul 05, 2017 3:41:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Falló en arranque del Contexto [/mbbn_mult_web_autodigitalweb_01] debido a errores previos
jul 05, 2017 3:41:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
jul 05, 2017 3:41:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
jul 05, 2017 3:41:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 841 ms
```

Estuve intentando desde eliminar el proyecto y volverlo a poner y de ese error no se quita, es un proyecto Maven arquitectura Spring.

```
Especificamente es este error:

ADVERTENCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:mbbn_mult_web_autodigitalweb_01' did not find a matching property.
```

Que no permite ejecutar el proyecto.

Espero y me puedan ayudar de antemano les mando un cordial saludo.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bbva.jee.arq.spring.core.util.ArqSpringContextLoaderListener` es muy claro. No está bajando todas las dependencias, así que en tiempo de compilación falla. Haz lo que dice Borja Diago y al eitmpo, confirma que no necesitas configurar algún repositorio Maven de tu empresa (que sea `com.bbva.jee` da a entender que es una libreríá de tu empresa/ciente/proyecto)

Answer (score 2):

Prueba a borrar el directorio `repository` de la carpeta `.m2` y actualizar `maven` de nuevo.

A veces ocurre que te descargas los archivos corruptos o incompletos.